# Firebase functions expires after a day

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Realtime database and also firebase functions service(node.js).
In node.js is have this listener:

```
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
//some logic
});
```

when I'm deploying this code(firebase deploy) it works fine as expected.
but some time after(~day) ,it stops listening and does nothing.
Of course I don't see any crash or errors that can explain that.
basically I need this listener to run forever.
Am I doing something wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: There's nothing in the code you shared that would cause the listener to auto-detach after a day. You might want to check the logging output for network messages or other relevant messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not supported by Cloud Functions.  You can't have a listener run indefinitely like this.  Cloud Functions is designed to let you write code that responds to events in other Google products.  You have to define a function and the criteria to match the event.  [See the documentation for writing Realtime Database triggers.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)

After you do define a function that matches the events you want to process, your function will have a default timeout of 60 seconds to complete its work, configurable to a maximum of 9 minutes.  Any work happening in that function will be shut down after that time.  So, you shouldn't be using any persistent listeners like `on()`.  Use `once()` instead to read data.